# Why does ToStringBuilder work inconsistently?

Tags: java, tostring, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang, apache-commons-lang3

In the following code, why do the two lines containing `System.out.println(person);` yield different outputs? The second line indirectly calls the method `Job.toString` yielding the string `"Manager"`, but the first line mysteriously does not yielding `Job@28f67ac7`. The line in between `person.put("a", "b");` doesn't seem to me like it should make any difference.

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.*;

class Job extends HashMap<String, String> {
    @Override public String toString() {
        return "Manager";
    }
}

class Person extends HashMap<String, String> {
    Job job;

    Person() {
        this.job = new Job();
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this);
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        System.out.println(person);
        person.put("a", "b");
        System.out.println(person);
    }
}
```

Console:

```
Person@2b80d80f[job=Job@28f67ac7,threshold=0,loadFactor=0.75]
Person@2b80d80f[job=Manager,threshold=12,loadFactor=0.75]
```

Comment: Can I suggest that extending `HashMap` like this is almost certainly not as useful as you think. A `Person` isn't a `HashMap`; they might *have* a `HashMap` of attributes, though, so composition would be a more appropriate relationship here.

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree, extending HashMap is not useful in this example. But considering that the example is contrived, would you have expected to get inconsistent outputs?

Comment: @BrianSchack no, I wouldn't. I can see no logical explanation for this behavior, aside from poor implementation of the `ToStringBuilder` class.

Comment: @cricket_007 The Override annotation is optional. I added it in, but it doesn't change the output.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, I am afraid that I might have stumbled on a bug in Apache Commons. I have been reading through the source code, but I can't seem to find where it is though.

Comment: Thoughts:  are you sure you are using a good version of A C?  Looking at the corresponding version of the A C source code?   You should be able to track down where the badness happens using a debugger.

Comment: @AndyTurner I opened an issue (LANG-131) on the Apache Commons issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-1381

Comment: @StephenC Yes, I am using the latest version (3.7) of commons-lang and the corresponding source code. I have not yet been able to track down where the badness happens –– hence this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2 things contribute to the output changing:

- ToStringBuilder avoids calling toString() on equal instances to avoid infinite recursions.
- Your Person and Job classes inherit HashMap's equals() method, causing `new Person().equals(new Job()) == true`

This means while person and person.job in your example remain equal to each other, ToStringBuilder will not call person.job.toString(), but when the map contents change, person.job.toString() will be called.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!